# ArcObjects Tool via Model Builder?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have created a series of custom tools using Arcobjects (VB.NET) that reside in a toolbar.  Each launches a windows form, takes some parameters and then performs its task.

Is it possible to hook into these via ModelBuilder?  The idea is to allow the user to leverage the iteration capabilities in model builder to vary one of the parameters and run iterative, 'hands-free' testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the provided functionality in a geoprocessing function tool with a given set of input and output parameters. Then it can be used in many ways, such as directly from ArcToolbox, from the commandline, Python script or from Modelbuilder.

For details, see [Custom geoprocessing function tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mrs000000).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Must have missed it in the documentation.